# Hotspot Internet Problem

Tags: stock-android, connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, lenovo

I am giving hotspot to laptop via android mobile but in laptop it is showing there is no any internet connection when I connect via laptop wifi. In my android phone I am using internet with 4g speed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow these steps? Have you set a password for your hotspot?

Please click on this link [Share a mobile connection by tethering or hotspot on Android](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9059108?hl=en-GB)

> Tether by Wi-Fi hotspot You can share your phone’s mobile data with up
>   to 10 other devices via a Wi-Fi hotspot.
>
> **Step 1:** Turn on your phone's hotspot Open your phone's Settings app.
>   Tap Network & Internet and then Hotspot & tethering. Tap Wi-Fi
>   hotspot. Turn on Wi-Fi hotspot. To see or change a hotspot setting,
>   such as the name or password, tap it. If needed, first tap Set up
>   Wi-Fi hotspot. Tip: If you don't want your hotspot to require a
>   password, pick None under 'Security'.
>
> **Step 2:** Connect another device to your phone's hotspot On the other
>   device, open that device's list of Wi-Fi options. Pick your phone's
>   hotspot name. Enter your phone's hotspot password. Click Connect.

Comment: Issue not solved.

Comment: @PAWANJAIN Check that your telephone operator allows the possibility of tethering or hotspot. Sometimes this possibility is not available or is not included in the telephone tariff.